# Is it correct to use "build" in the headline "The safest Olympic Stadium build ever"?

Tags: verb-forms, past-participles

I found this article on the Internet but I wonder if there may be a mistake in the headline:

> The safest Olympic Stadium **build** ever: Olympic Park to receive prestigious safety award ([source](http://www.mirror.co.uk/sport/other-sports/london-2012-olympic-park-to-receive-833783))

Shouldn't "built", past participle, be used instead of "build"?

Comment: Also, this build seems to refer to the 'Big Build'. From the linked article: *"More than 12,500 workers helped construct the venues and the ‘Big Build’ of the site has been hailed as the safest construction of an Olympic Stadium ever."*

Comment: Interestingly enough the same article has a mistake in my opinion: _Olympic park build completed with out a single death_ - should be without

Comment: Compare with "the most stable build of the software system so far".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, the headline is correct.

You can use the word "build" as a noun to mean "building project". This headline is saying that the project to build the stadium was the safest ever. In other words, very few people were hurt while building the stadium.

If you said, "safest Olympic Stadium ever built", that's also correct, but it would mean that the stadium itself was the safest ever. In this case, it would be very safe to enter the stadium after it was built.

Comment: It's correct, but it would look odd in flowing text. It's jargony, but it's also short, so it works well in a headline.

Comment: @TRiG I agree... It's definitely "headline-speak". There are much clearer ways to express the idea if you don't have a character limit.

Answer (score -2):

"The safest Olympic Stadium build" can just be used to refer to the Olympic Stadium - the way it is built is the safest. Not so much the actual building process; just the stadium itself. "The safest Olympic Stadium built" would basically get across the same point, but it isn't exactly the same thing.

But uhm reading that article, in this case it probably is talking about the actual building process.

"Build 2.0" or something is also like version 2.0 of some sort of application - another example of build as a noun.